# Noindex Page should appear in Google sitelinks

Tags: seo, google-search, noindex

I have a page e.g Sign-Up.php in my website, I want this page should not be indexed by google but it should appear in Sitelinks of my website when searched on google.

Is it good idea to use the following tag on my Sign-Up.php?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow, noarchive" />
```

I know google decides which page are candidate for sitelinks.

Answer (score 1):

IF you add noindex, Google will not index this page and also will not add it to the sitelinks.